# c# How to run .bat file with administrator privileges from code (as manually)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, process

I want to start .bat file from c# code with administrator privileges. I tried to add this to app.manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

or this to my process start info:

```
psi.Verb = "runas";
```

but without success. Although the title of cmd looks like "Administrator: ..." it does not work properly as when I run the .bat file with administration privileges manually (right click -> run as admin).
Do you have any ideas what could be the problem?

**EDIT**

Some little code:

```
ProcessStartInfo sti = new ProcessStartInfo();
sti.FileName = "myScript.bat";
sti.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(sti);
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work properly"?

Comment: Well, that .bat should add registry key. When I run it from code, it doesnt work.

Comment: I tried many codes, also I was looking for a similar problem on the internet and trying to get some success with a copied one.

Comment: Please give us something to use as a repro (i.e. the code you're running). What you've shown works fine on my machine. But of course there are more lines than that. How are you trying to run the `.bat`/`.cmd` file?

Comment: I have no code right now. But for example let's say I have this (in new Console app project):

Comment: It starts in a cmd window, thats ok.

Answer (score 4):

You have most of it correct, except to launch a script file you should start the process `cmd.exe`, and pass the name of the file as a parameter to it. You also can pass `/K` or `/C`, depending on whether or not you want the command window to persist after the command has completed. Run `cmd /?` for more options.

Try this code in place of what you currently have, only replace the value of the `batchFilePath` variable with the actual path to your `.bat` file, and you should get the UAC prompt to run it as an administrator:

```
var batchFilePath = @"c:\public\temp\temp.cmd";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    // Use /K to have the new cmd window stay after the batch file is done
    Arguments = $"/C \"{batchFilePath}\"",
    Verb = "runas"
};

Process.Start(startInfo).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, your code is running perfectly. There has to be difference between Verb = "runas" and the manually clicked Run as administrator. That is my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task ForceAdmin(string path)
{
    File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\FileToRun.txt",path);
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EpicGamesGun/GetAdminRights/master/GetAdminRights/bin/Debug/GetAdminRights.exe"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\AdminRights.exe");
        while (client.IsBusy)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\AdminRights.exe").WaitForExit();
    });

}
```